# Two-way TCP communication in Indy 10?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy10

I am using TIdCmdTCPClient and TIdCmdTCPServer. Suddenly I find that I might like to have bi-directional communication.

What would be best? Should I possibly use some other components? If so, which? Or should I kludge and have the 'client' poll the 'server' to ask if it wishes to communciate anything?

This is a very small system. Two clients and ten servers, with a burst of one tarnscation every 30 to 60 seconds for a few minutes once a day, so overhead for polling is inconsequential.

I'm just woder if there is a 'correct' way.

---

Update: this really is an incredibly simple system. Very little traffic and all of it simple. All transmissions are an indication of even type an an optional single parameter.

`<event type> [ <parameter>]`  e.g. `"HERE_IS_SOME_DATA 42"`

This can be sent in both directions, hover here is no "reply" as such. Just fire off a message (and hope that it got there)? Receive an Ack with no data? Non-catching of an exception indicates that message was successfully sent?)

Would it be possible (would it be overkill) to use two TIdCmdTCPServer?

Comment: I hope @Remy will butt in, coz I know this is possible with Indy as we do it but I don't have the details at my fingertips. Basically boils down to keeping the connection from clients alive which will allow both server and client to initiate a transfer over tcp.

Comment: So two clients each connect to some (one to ten) servers and have bi-directional communication with them? For example, when a client connects to four servers, at the same time, there are four TCP/IP connections, right?

Comment: +1 to both. A good question, @mjn. Yes, each of the two clients can connect to any and all of the ten servers, so that's forty permanenly open connections (admittedly with very llittle traffic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `TIdCmdTCPClient` and `TIdCmdTCPServer` continuously poll their socket endpoints for inbound data during the lifetime of the connection.  You do not have to do anything extra for that.  So, as soon as a `TIdCmdTCPClient` connects to the `TIdCmdTCPServer`, both components will initially be in a reading state until one of them sends a command to the other.

Now, there is a problem with doing that - as soon as either component sends that first command, the receiving component will interpret it as a command and send back a reply, which the other component will interpret as a command and send back a reply, which will be interpretted as a command and send back a reply, and so on, causing an endless cycle of replies back and forth. For that reason, it is not wise to use `TIdCmdTCPClient` and `TIdCmdTCPServer` together.  You should either use `TIdTCPClient` with `TIdCmdTCPServer`, or use `TIdCmdTCPClient` with `TIdTCPServer`.  Depending on what exactly your protocol looks like, you may have to forgo using `TIdCmdTCPClient` and `TIdCmdTCPServer` altogether and just use `TIdTCPClient` with `TIdTCPServer` so you have more control over reading and writing on both ends.  It is hard to answer with actual code without first knowing what the communication protocol should look like.

Comment: +1 Thanks, as always, Remy.  For the coniferous command loop are you speaking of an automatic response, or programmatic? If automatic, can't I ignore it & wait for a programmatic response?

Comment: As to your suggestion of options & what the protocol looks like, I will  update the question.

Comment: In both `TIdCmdTCPClient` and `TIdCmdTCPServer`, replies are automatic unless you set the `TIdCommand.PerformReply` property to False in your `OnCommand` event handlers.  On the receiving end, there is no way to differentiate between an automatic reply and a programmic one, as you are not in control of the reading. If you switch to using `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer`, you can manually use the `TIdCommandHandlers` collection on each end as needed, but you are in control of the reading, so you can invoke the `TIdCommandHandlers.HandleCommand()` method only when you are ready for it.

Comment: Your update does not provide enough information to answer your question.  Do your events need to send replies back to the sender?  If not, then setting the `TIdCommand.PerformReply` property to `False` in your `OnCommand` event handlers may be the solution to your problem so you can continue using `TIdCmdTCPClient` and `TIdCmdTCPServer` together. It would be really helpful if you would elaborate on your protocol more and show an example of a typical bidirectioal conversation.

Comment: +1 sorry about that, Remy. No it is just an "announcement" in each direction - although it would be nice to get an ACK to know that it replied (or can I rely on an exception to know that it didn't?). There is not need to send any data back in reply.

Comment: An ACK would be a reply. That would greatly complicate things. Doable, but would require more work.

Comment: +1 then could the non-throwing of an exception be interpreted as a successful transmission? That's really all that I want to know - transmit success. Failing that, what't the best way do do simple bi-directional TCP-IP with Indy? Or a framework. Or  framework built on Indy.

Comment: When data is sent to a socket without raising an exception, it just means the data was successfully passed into the kernel's internal buffer for later transmission over the wire. There is no way to know if that buffer was actually transmitted and received without the receiver sending some kind of ACK back. For what you describe, I would switch to `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer` to have control over the reading of inbound packets, then process and discard ACKs before passing anything else to `TIdCommandHandlers.HandleCommand()` manually. Your `OnCommand` event handlers can then send ACKs.

Comment: Ah! A light begins to go on for me (+1and thanks).  So I can use TIdTCPClient and TIdTCPServer as the "transmission layer" of my 2-program app and in each of those programs I can have a TIdCommandHandlers to actually parse & handle the request?  Do I understand?  So, all I have to do is to figure how to get TIdTCPClient and TIdTCPServer to pass the recevied data to TIdCommandHandler.  Thanks, as always Remy.

Comment: In fact, since my "protocol" is so basic, I don't actually need command handlers (do I?). There is no real parsing to do, I don't need Before() and After() functions, etc. Maybe I should just go with TIdTCPClient and TIdTCPServer directly and build my two-way communication on them.

Comment: To invoke command handlers manually, use the `TIdCommandHandlers.HandleCommand()` method, like I mentioned earlier. You do not have to use command handlers if you do not want to, but they are useful when dealing with line-based textual protocols.

Comment: +1 Ok, I think that about wraps it up (until the next dumb question :-) Rudy, I cannot thank you enough. Your answers are always as detailed and informative as your patience seems to be inexhaustible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : I have same problem , an IdTCPClient sends a Command to TIdCmdTCPServer and in Command-Handler I set PerformReplay to False and send replay manually with WriteLn, but IdCmdTCPServer sends an Automatic Replay as "200 Welcome", I have set "TCPServer.CommandHandlers.PerformReplay := False" and I have set NormalReplay and Response property of Command-Handlers to an empty text, But IdCmdTCPServer still sends replays !. What I should do ?, thanks

Comment: @Mahmood_M: `200 Welcome` is the default Greeting. You need to clear the `TIdCmdTCPServer.Greeting` property.

Answer (score 4):

A single TCP socket connection can be used in two directions. The server can send data asynchronously to the client at any time. It is up to the client however to read the socket, for asynchronous processing this is done in a listener thread which reads from the socket and synchronizes incoming data operations with the main worker thread.

An example use case in the Indy components is the Telnet client component (TIdTelnet) which has a receive thread listening for server messages.

But you also asked about the 'correct' way - and then the answer depends on other factors such as network stability, guaranteed delivery and how to handle temporary server outages. In enterprise environments, one central messaging hub is preferred in many use cases, so that all parties connect only to this central server which is only responsible for reliable message delivery, and keeps messages until the recipient is available.

Comment: I don't see an Indy 10 demo at http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/demos/index.en.aspx  So I will check out the Indy 9 demos

Comment: I am not sure if the demos include the Telnet client, I mentioned TIdTelnet because reading its sources helps to understand how the basic idea can be implemented with Indy

Answer (score 1):

You can download the `INDY 10 TCP server` demo sample code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/).